# File icons on desktop moving left when they are renamed

Tags: windows-11, icons, desktop, rename

Sometimes when I rename a file on my Desktop, the icon position gets reset to a position in the top left corner.

- My PC is running Windows 11 Home, version 22H2, OS Build 22621.3155.
- "Auto arrange icons" is disabled.
- The same issue is occuring on my friend's PC
- The issue doesn't affect all files. Mainly seems to effect images.

How do I prevent icons on my desktop from moving when I rename them?

[image: Icon moving when renamed]

Comment: According to Windows, the Desktop is just a folder like any other; that is the cause of this problem. The only thing I know that fixes this is DisplayFusion which can store the location of icons on the desktop but thats a workaround. https://www.displayfusion.com/Features/DesktopIconProfiles/

Comment: Oh and UltraMon does too

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: +1 just for the BOMB GIF and well written question

Answer (score 0):

A workaround by [NCMAP on the Microsoft Forums](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-do-i-stop-renamed-files-from-moving-to-upper/9713d239-71e9-4369-952e-f666e4594d08?page=5) worked for me.

> 1. Right click on your desktop
> 2. Choose "Personalize"
> 3. On the right hand side list, choose "Start"
> 4. Turn off Show recently opened items in "Start, Jump Lists, and File Explorer"

Unfortunately, this also disables the list of recently opened items in the start menu, the jump lists when right clicking a program in the taskbar, and the sidebar of File Explorer. The list of recently opened items is not restored when re-enabling this setting either, meaning it will need to be repopulated over time.

Answer (score -2):

If this is still happening when booting in Safe mode, then
this is a Windows behavior that is not affected by installed
third-party products.

You should first try to find if this is a problem with Windows:

- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
- [Repair Install Windows 11 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/repair-install-windows-11-with-an-in-place-upgrade.418/).
  This is a rather heavy operation that is equivalent to a major
  Windows upgrade, but should conserve apps and settings
  (but take precautions). It's unlikely to do better than DISM/SFC,
  so it's mostly for the case where any problem was found by them.

If no solution is found as above, the only solution left is to
use a software that can remember the icons layout and return it
when needed.

Some such free products that I have used are :

- [ReIcon](https://www.sordum.org/8366/reicon-v2-0-restore-desktop-icon-layouts/)
- [Iconoid](https://web.archive.org/web/20230903122924/https://www.sillysot.com/)

You will find more such products in the
[ReIcon Alternatives page](https://alternativeto.net/software/reicon/).

Comment: sillysot.com is a spam link (the iconoid link)

Comment: @Gantendo: sillysot.com is gone, but Iconoid can still be downloaded from the Internet Archive, so the link was replaced. A pity, since I find it very useful.